# Calculating no. of transactions placed within an hour in php

Tags: datetime, timestamp, php

I have following data about transactions placed on the same day (PHP):

```
Transaction id       Date/Time
```

```
111-11111            05:50:07
```

```
211-21111            06:02:58
```

```
241-21311            06:43:00
```

```
255-26711            07:58:00
```

How can I check, **if all of these transactions has been placed within same hour (single hour)**? I am little lost here and need direction.

Thank you.

Comment: It is in a txt file, from which it can be easily retrieved.

Comment: And "within an hour", does it mean e.g. from 07:00-07:59 , or also from e.g. 07:33-08:32

Comment: It should cover 07:33-08:32 as well..

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're still looking for this but for anyone else who may be looking for something similar, here is what I have so far.

```
<?php

$transactions = array(
    '111-11111' => '05:50:07',
    '211-21111' => '06:02:58',
    '241-21311' => '06:43:00',
    '255-26711' => '07:58:00'
);

list($hour, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', array_shift($transactions));
$first   = (new DateTime())->setTime($hour, $minutes, $seconds);
$endtime = $first->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
foreach ($transactions as $key => $time) {
    list($hour, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $time);
    $datetime = (new DateTime())->setTime($hour, $minutes, $seconds);
    printf("Transaction ID: %s, Date/Time: %s, Within an hour: %s<br>\n",
        $key,
        $time,
        ($datetime < $endtime ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    );
}
```

Basically it takes the first record and uses that as the baseline and then loops through the other records and checks to see if they are within one hour of the first record.

[**See it in action**](http://3v4l.org/9o5re)